# Incorrect encoding of allure report

Tags: maven, allure

I got an error while building allure report with `mvn site` command.

Non-latin characters are represented as '????' in .html report, though characters are properly encoding in .xml files in /allure-reports folder.

surefire-plugin section looks like below. I also use UTF-8 key, when executing 'mvn clean install site' in command line.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${version.aspectj}/aspectjweaver-${version.aspectj}.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
            </property>
            <!--<systemPropertyVariables>-->
            <!--<browser_type>${browser_type}</browser_type>-->
            <!--</systemPropertyVariables>-->
        </properties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${version.aspectj}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in version 1.4.4. Fixed in 1.4.5

All information about releases you can find here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/releases

Comment: Thank you! i'll try new version and will be back with the result soon.

Comment: Yes, it's fixed in 1.4.5

Comment: @malover glad to hear. Could you please mark answer as the right one?